# div onclick not working in imageFlow ipad

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

In ipad onclick event is not working on div . In imageFlow code i have replaced all images with div but on ipad on click event is not working .

i tried changing following on click into touch and touchstart but nothing working on it.

```
switch (image.i == my.imageID) {
    case false:

        image.onclick = function () {
            //$('.slideDiv').removeClass('imgnew');                         
            alert('each time called');
            my.glideTo(this.i);
        };
        break;

    default:
        this.zIndex = my.zIndex + 1;
        if (image.url !== '') {
            image.onclick = my.onClick;

        }
        break;
}
```

I Tried,

```
$(image).click()
$(image).live('click toch touchstart', function () {
    // ...
});
```

adding cursor pointer,
adding onClick()=""  on div

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent,
event = (ua.match(/iPad/i)) ? "touchstart" : "click";

$(image).bind(event, function(e) {
   //do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For touch event, use this.

```
$('image').on('vclick', function() {
    // your scripts...      
});
```